# Error of not finding the value, but I used the similar method earlier to retrieve the documents

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on Post Comment feed, in which there is a comment button which should lead to the comments list related to the particular post. But when I am trying to implement method it is saying invalid optional value, I used similar thing earlier to get the comments. but now it's not working please tell me where I am going wrong

```
class HomeViewController: UITableViewController {
    var posts = [Post]()
    var db: Firestore!
    var postKey:String = ""
    private var documents: [DocumentSnapshot] = []
    private var listener : ListenerRegistration!
    var postId1:String = ""
    var detailView: Post!
    var onlyforPostKey: Post?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        db = Firestore.firestore()
        retrieveAllPosts()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @objc func handleLogout(_ sender:Any) {
        try! Auth.auth().signOut()
        self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
    }

    func retrieveAllPosts(){
        let postsRef = Firestore.firestore().collection("posts").limit(to: 50)
        postsRef.getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            } else {
                if let snapshot = snapshot {
                    for document in snapshot.documents {
                        let data = document.data()
                        let username = data["post_author_username"] as? String ?? ""
                        let postTitle = data["postTitle"] as? String ?? ""
                        let postcategory = data["postcategory"] as? String ?? ""
                        let postContent = data["postContent"] as? String ?? ""
                        let postAuthorProfilePicUrl = data["post_user_profile_pic_url"] as? String ?? ""
                        let postAuthorSpinnerC = data["post_author_spinnerC"] as? String
                        let newSourse = Post(_documentId: document.documentID, _username: username, _postTitle: postTitle, _postcategory: postcategory, _postContent: postContent, _postuserprofileImagUrl: postAuthorProfilePicUrl, _postAuthorSpinncerC: postAuthorSpinnerC)
                        self.posts.append(newSourse)
                        print(self.postKey)
                    }
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        //tableView.reloadData()
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return posts.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "postCell", for: indexPath) as! PostTableViewCell
        cell.btnComment.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.btnComment.addTarget(self, action: #selector(toComments(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        cell.set(post: posts[indexPath.row])
        return cell
    }

    @objc func toComments(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        let buttonPosition = sender.convert(CGPoint.zero, to: tableView)
        let indexPath: IndexPath? =  tableView.indexPathForRow(at: buttonPosition)
        detailView = posts[(indexPath?.row)!]
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "toCommentsList", sender: nil)
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        postKey = onlyforPostKey!._documentId
        var vc = segue.destination as! CommentListViewController
        vc.postId = postKey
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let post = self.posts[indexPath.row]
    }
}
```

Comment: "it is saying invalid optional value" Where?

Comment: @Larme I am facing the error of "Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value
"

Comment: When posting questions, please provide detailed information - what line is crashing? Did you step through the code to see what var is nil? Also, on this line *let postAuthorSpinnerC = data["post_author_spinnerC"] as? String* there's no nil coalescing so that may be the culprit.

Comment: @Jay the issue has been resolved for now by myself, if any thing else is required , i will let you know